# Import all Sheets from a given Excel File

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I want to import all sheets of an Excel without defining them in an Array. In the Documentation i found following solution:

INFO:
I dont want to store any Information of the Excel File in a Database.

In my Laravel-Controller:

```
$workbook = new Workbook();
$resultData =  Excel::import($workbook, 'MyExcel.xlsx', 'public');
```

My Workbook.php

```
class Workbook implements ToArray, WithEvents
{
    public function array(array $array)
    {

    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeSheet::class => function(BeforeSheet $event) {
                dd($event);
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

If I do this, the Event is never triggered and following error is shown:

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Is there a possibility to tell my Laravel-Excel Package not to use any Database-Connections.

Comment: Where you want store import data without database?

Comment: I want to handle the data in my controller and do something with it.